# Is the orientation double cover unique?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

My question comes from the following. We usually say "the universal cover" because, as we know, it is unique up to isomorphism on the adequate category (in particular, every universal cover is homeomorphic to each other).

I never dwelled in thinking about the orientation double cover. I just read its construction and knew that, if a manifold is orientable, the construction would yield two copies of the manifold. If it is not orientable, it will yield a connected orientable manifold. And unconsciously I absorbed the fact that it should be "unique". But it seems like it isn't the case.

For instance, take $\mathbb{R}P^3$. It is orientable and, as such, its orientation double cover should be two disjoint $\mathbb{R}P^3$. But $S^3$, through the projection, is also a double cover, and orientable, and obviously $S^3$ is not homeomorphic to two disjoint $\mathbb{R} P^3$.

Therefore, I have these questions:

1) Am I getting something wrong? (For instance, is my implicit definition of orientation double cover as a two-fold orientable cover wrong?)
EDIT: Thanks @GrumpyParsnip for telling me that my definition is wrong. Based on the answers, I think I didn't get my intention with this question clear. Now that my definition is "wrong", I'll ask: **Why** defining it the way it is? What makes **this special** cover... special? Why not allow any two-fold orientable cover to be a orientation double cover?

2) Does this issue not happen when the base manifold is non-orientable?

Comment: Yes, you are getting the definition wrong. The orientation double cover is not simply a 2-fold orientable cover.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip What is the definition, then? Simply the manifold obtained by the standard construction? (my problem with this is that it sounds artificial and not natural to restrict to a given construction)

Comment: As Lee Mosher points out, there is homomorphism $OR:\pi_1(M)\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. The orientation double cover is the cover associated to the kernel of this homomorphism. (Recall that covers are in 1-1 correspondence with subgroups of $\pi_1(M)$.)

Comment: The definition of the orientable double cover of $M$ is the space of ordered pairs $(x,O)$ where $x \in M$ and $O$ is one of the two local orientations of $M$ at $x$. If you pick an atlas for $M$ consisting solely of open sets which are open discs, then for each atlas element $U$ of $M$ there is a corresponding pair of atlas elements of the orientable double cover, one for each of the two orientations of $U$.

Comment: As for the why, I think it's in the name. It's the double cover associated to the orientations on $M$. Otherwise it's just an $\textit{orientable}$ double cover, with no particular connection to the orientations on $M$.

Comment: I guess the point here is if you have some manifold that is not orientable, then your orientation cover is path-connected. So it corresponds to index 2 subgroup of fundamental group of the manifold, hence it is unique( index 2 subgroup is normal, so there is only one conjugacy class). But if the manifold is orientable, orientation covering space is not path connected, so not any 2-fold cover is the orientation cover.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The orientation cover of a path connected manifold $M$ is indeed unique. To see why, there is a homomorphism $OR : \pi_1(M) \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which takes a closed path $\gamma$ to the nontrivial element of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is orientation reversing. If $OR$ is nontrivial then the orientation cover is the covering space corresponding to $\text{kernel}(OR)$. Otherwise, if $OR$ is trivial then the orientation cover is two copies of $M$.

Regarding your example of $\mathbb{R}P^3$, it is not too surprising that some orientable manifolds have orientable double covering spaces. Any closed orientable surface (except the 2-sphere) is an example.